# how compactly use multiple or's within a select

Tags: kdb

Say I have a table

```
tbl:([]a:`XXY`XXZ`XZZ`XYZ)

q)tbl
a  
---
XXY
XXZ
XZZ
XYZ
```

And I want to select the rows like "*XX*" or "*ZZ*"

Is there a more compact way than writing

```
select from tbl where (a like "*XX*")|(a like "*ZZ*")
```

Ideally I'd like to store all my or options in a variable and then pass that to the select.

I've tried using functional selects, but can only get it to work for a single or and only in the below form.

```
q)c:(like;`a;enlist "*XX*")
::
q)?[tbl;enlist c;0b;()]
a  
---
XXY
XXZ
```

Instead of setting enlist "*XX*" within c, could I create a table or list and then pass that into c?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most common approach would be

```
q)select from tbl where any a like/:("*XX*";"*ZZ*")
a
---
XXY
XXZ
XZZ
```

Answer (score 0):

Extend on @terrylynch answer
you can also pass the variable to the like statement. As mentioned by Terry, you can always use an adverb to extend the pattern matching or using a lambda and iterate through the list variable using adverb. In this case, using /: the straightforward way

```
q)tbl:([]a:`XXY`XXZ`XZZ`XYZ)
q)tbl
a
---
XXY
XXZ
XZZ
XYZ
q)pattern:("*XX*";"*ZZ*")
q)select from tbl where any a like/:pattern
a
---
XXY
XXZ
XZZ
q)select from tbl where any {x like y}[a;] each pattern
a
---
XXY
XXZ
XZZ
```